# Reactjs: setState with checkbox: checked or unchecked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently "testing the waters" with Reactjs. Based on [their docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), I have whipped up a small project that I'm stuck with. So far, when the checkbox is checked, the state changes but....not sure how to change a state unchecked:

```
var Foo = React.createClass{(
 getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      location: true,
    }
  },

 onClick: function() {
  this.setState({ location: false });
 },

 render: function() {

    var inlineStyles = {
      display: this.state.location ? 'block' : 'none'
    };
  return (
   <div>
    <input type="checkbox"
     onClick={this.onClick}
    /> show / hide bar
    <hr />
    <div style={inlineStyles}>
     <p>bar</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  );
 }

)};
```

Do I need to use an `if statement` for the sort of thing I want? I need to `this.setState.location: true` when unchecked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to read the state of the checkbox during a click, and apply that to your React state.

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <input type="checkbox" onClick={this.onClick} checked={!this.state.location}></input>
    },
    
    onClick: function(e) {
        this.setState({location: !e.target.checked});
    },
    
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            location: true
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Properly use `checked={!this.state.location}` instead.

Comment: I was playing with the `value` but I could not understand. This makes sense. You may want to change the `getInitialState` to `true`. Works for me that way.

Comment: I edited the answer, took me a while to figure out why it wasn't working