# Way to pass props and display in a list in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am encountering issues when trying to display the props in an ordered list. It only displays the initial value. When I add to the list, it was not updated.

Here is the source code

```
TodoList.js

class ToDoList extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.data.map(list => {
                    return (
                        <ol key={list.uuid} > <input type="checkbox"></input>{list.uuid}- {list.text}</ol>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ToDoList;
```

```
Todo.js
let data = [{ uuid: 100, text: "TEST" }, { uuid: 101, text: "TEST" }];
let id = 0;

class Todo extends React.Component {
    handleAddItem = () => {
        id = id + 1;
        data.push({ uuid: id, text: this.refs.textInput.value });
        console.log(data);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" ref="textInput"></input>
                    <button onClick={this.handleAddItem}>ADD TO LIST</button>
                </div>
                <ToDoList data={data} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Todo;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I add to the list, it was not updated.

It's because `data` is **not** a state variable and **does not** cause a re-render.

To fix, make it a state instead.

```
class Todo extends React.Component {
  // make data and id a state variable
  state = {
    data: [{ uuid: 100, text: "TEST" }, { uuid: 101, text: "TEST" }],
    id: 0,
  }
  ...
}
```

Then pass state `data` to `TodoList`

```
<ToDoList data={this.state.data} />
```

---

**WHEN UPDATING STATE**:

Never mutate a state variable in your handler by using [spread operator (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
handleAddItem = () => {
  // update the state using this.setState()
  this.setState(prevState => ({
      id: prevState.id + 1,
      data: [
        ...prevState.data, // use spread operator
        { uuid: prevState.id + 1, text: this.refs.textInput.value }
      ]
    }),
    () => console.log(this.state.data) // pass 2nd arg to log state update
  );
}
```

Comment: I have additional question, for the todoList.js file, how to check if the checkbox is checked and make the text 'line-through'?

Comment: Given you have a list of checkboxes, you can have a state object to track each checkboxes' `checked` state. Then add conditional styling based on `this.state.checked[e.target.id]`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33208629/reactjs-setstate-with-checkbox-checked-or-unchecked) as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `state` to `ToDo` component add use `setSate()` method to update `state`. Then the `ToDo` component and `ToDoList` component will re-render.

```
let data = [{ uuid: 100, text: "TEST" }, { uuid: 101, text: "TEST" }];
let id = 0;

class Todo extends React.Component {
    state = {
        data
    }

    handleAddItem = () => {
        id = id + 1;
        this.setSate({
            data: [...this.state.data, { uuid: id, text: this.refs.textInput.value }]
        });
        console.log(this.state.data);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" ref="textInput"></input>
                    <button onClick={this.handleAddItem}>ADD TO LIST</button>
                </div>
                <ToDoList data={this.state.data} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

There is the [doucment](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) about `Component State`. Read it to learn more.